# Retrieve the last 5 years data using Entity Framework Linq

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I need to retrieve the last 5 years data on the below query.Can you tell me how can I do that ?

```
 var propertyIdList = (from property in _context.Properties
                       .Where(p => p.CreationTime >= condition for 5 years data restriction)
                        select new PropertyIdListDto
                                    {
                                        Id = property.Id,
                                    }).OrderBy(p => p.Id).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

I know how to do that with TSQL.But I need to do it with Linq.

**TSQL (sample):**

```
SELECT *
  FROM products
 WHERE date_column >= add_months( sysdate, -12*5 )
```

Comment: p.CreationTime >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5)

Comment: Use EntityFuctions.AddYears or DbFunctions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
var fiveYearsBackDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5);
var propertyIdList = (from property in _context.Properties
                       .Where(p => p.CreationTime >= fiveYearsBackDate)
                        select new PropertyIdListDto
                                    {
                                        Id = property.Id,
                                    }).OrderBy(p => p.Id).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: it gives this run time exception : Can you tell me why ? `System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddYears(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
`

Comment: don't add it inline calculate the date separately like i have done in the example.

Comment: Oh..Got that.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help, please accept the answer if you are happy with it.